# Conditionally dispatch an action depending on result of previous action

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have two actions: **validate** and **update**. Both can be dispatched independently, but I would also like that if the update action is dispatched, it first dispatches the validate action and only continues if there were no validations.

If this were synchronous code it would be something like:

```js
if (this.backendService.isValid(dataset)) {
    this.backEndService.update(dataset)
}
```

The definition of the two actions (and their corresponding success and error actions):

```js
export const validateDataset = createAction('[Datasets API] Validate Dataset', props<{ dataset: DataSetDto }>());
export const validateDatasetSuccess = createAction('[Datasets API] Validate Dataset Success', props<{ validationErrors: SgErrorMessage[]}>());
export const validateDatasetFail = createAction('[Datasets API] Validate Dataset Fail', props<{ error: string }>());

export const updateDataset = createAction('[Datasets API] Update Dataset', props<{ dataset: DataSetDto }>());
export const updateDatasetSuccess = createAction('[Datasets API] Update Dataset Success');
export const updateDatasetFail = createAction('[Datasets API] Update Dataset Fail', props<{ errorEntity: SgErrorEntity }>());
```

---

**Attempt 1**

If I have an effect listening for `updateDataset` and attempts to dispatch first `validateDataset` it never seems to get used when `.pipe()` is applied (and probably here I should use a selector like `hasValidationErrors` returning bool instead of also using `filter` operator):

```js
updateDataset$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(DatasetApiActions.updateDataset),
        mergeMap(action => of(DatasetPageActions.validateDataset({dataset: action.dataset})).pipe(
            withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getValidationErrors))),
            filter(([action, validationErrors]) => validationErrors.length > 0),
            mergeMap(([action, validationErrors]) => this.datasetService.editDataSet(action.dataset).pipe(
                map(() => DatasetApiActions.updateDatasetSuccess()),
                catchError(error => of(DatasetApiActions.updateDatasetFail({error})))
            ))
        ))
    );
});
```

---

**Attempt 2**

I tried to instead I split it up into a `saveDataset` action that should call both `validateDataset` and `updateDataset` actions sequentially, and also filter the `updateDataset` to only run if the `validationErrors` state is empty. I used `concatMap` so the actions could trigger sequentially and they probably are but the success/fail responses come in later and so the validation data can't be used:

```js
saveDataset$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(DatasetPageActions.saveDataset),
        concatMap(action => concat(
            of(DatasetPageActions.validateDataset({dataset: action.dataset})),
            of(DatasetApiActions.updateDataset({dataset: action.dataset}))
        ))
    );
});

updateDataset$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(DatasetApiActions.updateDataset),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getValidationErrors))),
        filter(([action, validationErrors]) => validationErrors.length == 0),
        tap(([action, validationErrors]) => console.log("validationErrors: " + validationErrors))
    );
}, {dispatch: false});
```

---

Maybe I'm thinking about it the wrong way and the validation should be built as an async forms validation instead, but I still think the question is valid.

What I'm struggling with is that I can't add an effect to the `validateDatasetSuccess` action to trigger the `updateDataset` action because that may be dispatched by the user separately (and not only by saving). Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Is the validation an async action?

Comment: @AndreiGătej yes, it's a call to a server side validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```js
updateDataset$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(DatasetApiActions.updateDataset),

    // dispatch the `validate` action
    tap(action => this.store.dispatch(DatasetPageActions.validateDataset({dataset: action.dataset}))),

    switchMap(
      action => this.store.pipe(
        select(getValidationErrors),
        
        // we want to skip the current state
        // after all, the store is just a `BehaviorSubject`,
        // so subscribing to it will return the current state
        skip(1),
        filter(validationErrors => /* ... your condition here ... */),
        mapTo(action),
      ),
    ),
    mergeMap(
      action => this.datasetService.editDataSet(action.dataset).pipe(
        map(() => DatasetApiActions.updateDatasetSuccess()),
        catchError(error => of(DatasetApiActions.updateDatasetFail({error})))
      )
    )
  );
});
```

Comment: Amazing! It does indeed work, and now I'll have some studying to do to understand it in detail, so thanks too for the comments :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I could elaborate on what's not very clear, just let me know!